# Script: fixed background attachment

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, background-attachment

Some forums I use don't have fixed backgrounds and I find it dizzying. I was hoping to change that with the TamperMonkey plugin but it requires scripts and I don't know how to create scripts. I found one similar albeit older topic and the scripts didn't work.

So, say I want to turn something like this:
`body {background: url('image') fixed;}` or `body {background-image: url('image');background-attachment: fixed;}`
Into a script. How would I go about that? I use Firefox, not sure if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript equivalent for setting those two properties would be:

```
document.body.style.background = "url('image')";
document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
```

I'm not familiar with TamperMonkey (I had to Google what it is), but I imagine if you saved those two lines in a .js file, and added them to be loaded on whichever pages you want to override the background, that should work.

If it doesn't work, feel free to drop me a comment and I can try to help you debug it.